# Can i install only HDFS from HDP?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, hdp

I want to use HDFS as a place to store data for Spark on Kubernetes. So i only need hdfs from HDP. But i'm wondering if i can install it without all other HDP components. Can i do this? If yes than how?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Hortonworks at all. In fact, the Spark from HDP is only compiled to specifically run in a YARN environment.

You can download Spark with HDFS from `spark.apache.org`, which will also include the k8s scheduler

Personally, I would recommend using Ceph (the Rook CNCF project), MinIO, or GlusterFS, instead of HDFS in a k8s cluster. Each of these options are capable of using the Hadoop FS APIs